# Mailman Service Masked After Debian 11 Upgrade

Tags: debian, mailman

After I performed the Debian 10 to 11 upgrade, for whatever odd reason my Mailman service became masked:

```
# service status mailman
status: unrecognized service
root@tester1:~# service mailman status
● mailman.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit mailman.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Can someone tell me how to unmask this service, thanks?

Comment: I am not using it anymore, but I know Mailman has major rewrite from v2 to v3 and for the latter the service is called `mailman3`. I am not sure if v2 is still supported. Which version of Mailman do you have?

Comment: Apparently, I have version 1.  I tried #apt-get install mailman3  which finished with bunches of errors.  And #apt remove mailman says that mailman isn't installed.